# Proteger imagenes de un directorio pero que a su vez se vean

Tags: php

Tengo un listado de empleados con su foto correspondiente. Desde el fichero robots.txt de Google he activado un disallow para cada imagen. Pero mi pregunta es la siguiente  como puedo hacer para que las imagenes se vean y a su vez que no se puedan acceder a ese directorio? no se si se puede hacer?
Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Si te refieres a que tienes un servidor web, y en un directorio desde el que éste sirve contenido están las imágenes, quieres que individualmente la URL de cada una muestre la imagen, pero que la URL del directorio no muestre el listado de todas ellas... si el servidor web es Apache puedes crear un archivo `.htaccess` en el mismo, y añadir la siguiente línea:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Si el fichero ya existe, añade esa línea al principio.

Si además quieres evitar que otras web con otros dominios hagan hot linking (incluir enlaces de permitan visualizar tus ficheros e imágenes en sus ficheros HTML) de los ficheros en ese directorio y los directorios hijos, también se puede añadir lo siguiente:

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?miweb.es [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https://www.miweb/sinfoto.jpg [NC,R,L]
```

Donde `miweb.es` es el dominio donde si permites que se incluyan las imágenes, ya sea usando `www` o sin ésto al principio.

Comment: He añadido lo que me has dicho y si las imagenes ya no se ven , me aparece: Error 403.Sería correcto el mensaje que aparece?

Comment: Correcto, el error 403 significa que el acceso está prohibido.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Por otro lado el fichero robots.txt con el disallow de la imagenes que tengo ya no sería necesario?

Comment: Yo lo dejaría, con eso evitas que buscadores como Google, que intentan URLs directamente sin necesitar listar el directorio, procesen esas imágenes para que estén accesibles desde el buscador.

Comment: Muchas gracias Vicente por tu ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: De nada. Acuerdate de marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te haya parecido más adecuada.

Comment: Si ya he añadido la respuesta más adecuada. Perdona el desconocimiento pero desde que  llevo aquí registrado hace más  de dos años, he vuelto hace pocos días.

Answer (score 1):

Claro que se puede, es muy sencillo. Coloca en el directorio a proteger un archivo index.php y por si las moscas un index.html

Te has fijado como protege Wordpress sus directorios? O cómo hacen la mayoría de plugins para protegerse?

Usan esto

```
<?php
// Silence is golden.
```

Yo uso esto en mis plugins

```
<?php
    echo '<center><br/><br/>Get Out Here !!!</center>';
```

Un archivo index lo que hace es que no permite ver el árbol de archivos del directorio. Hay algunos que lo ponen vacío y otros que se ponen más creativos. Imagínate que en el index de tus imágenes mandes a ver la [Rick Roll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)...

También puedes hacerlo con el htaccess, pero vamos, si no es una tarea compleja y monumental con un index vale.

Cuando hice un sistema de RRHH hace unos años, al momento de crear la carpeta que contendría todas las imágenes y archivos del empleado, también creaba un index.php que me libraba de esos líos.

---

Solo para aclarar: con `Options -Indexes` en el .htaccess de la raíz de tu sitio, evitas que se listen los archivos en los directorios donde no hay un archivo index. Pero si tu quieres puedes hacer un index personalizado a tu gusto, este index puede decir algo, redireccionar o hacer lo que tu quieras.

Comment: Cuidado porque haciendo eso bloqueas esa carpeta, pero no las nuevas subcarpetas que crees, tendrías entonces que poner esos ficheros index.php y index.html en cada una de las subcarpetas cuando las fueras creando.

Comment: Si, eso fue lo que puse de ultimo, que cuando creaba una carpeta por empleado dentro de la carpeta general de archivos creaba un index por cada carpeta. Es cierto que en el htaccess se puede con `Options -Indexes` pero yo solo di una opción personalizada.

Comment: Gracias por tus indicaciones. Sobre lo que indicas de wordpress, esta web la estoy haciendo desde cero. Esta claro que puede dar más  trabajo que crearla con wordpress pero  no hay otra opción.

Comment: La verdad que lo que buscas no es nada complicado. Como resuelvas tus problemas es algo que te dará experiencia y conocimiento a futuro. Me alegra que te sirvieran las respuestas, si gustas marca alguna como aceptada para no dejarla huérfana y si aun no resuelves tu duda dinos y te ayudamos...